# Hide label when variable equals to zero

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

I want to hide a StopWatch label when its equals to 0, How can I do this using conditional operator?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace FileTransfer_Socket_Client
{
class transferRate
{
    static Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    public static void timeLeft()
    {
        Thread StimeLeft = new Thread(Start);
        StimeLeft.Start();
    }

    private static void Start()
    {
        int rate = 0;
        int left = 0;
        int prevSum = 0;
        stopWatch.Start();
        while (fileTransfer.client.Connected)
        {
            if (fileTransfer.sum != 0)
            {
                rate = (fileTransfer.sum-prevSum)/1024;
                left = ((fileTransfer.fileSize - fileTransfer.sum)/ 1024) / rate;
                TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(left);
                Program.mainForm.AppendLabel(string.Format("{0}kb/s  timeleft: {1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D2}", rate, t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds));
                prevSum = fileTransfer.sum;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();
        stopWatch.Reset();
    }
}}
```

Comment: Yes, the simple and fast way is using an if statement...

Comment: Please only post the relevant portion of the code, including example.

Comment: Why do you not want to use an `if` statement? Would you be happy using the conditional operator instead? Do you suffer from the misguided notion that more lines of code makes your program run more slowly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there are more "interesting" ways to get this done, an `if/else` is the most basic way:

```
if (t.TotalMinutes < 1) {
   Program.mainForm.AppendLabel(string.Format("{0}kb/s  timeleft: {1:D2}", rate, t.Seconds));
} else {
   Program.mainForm.AppendLabel(string.Format("{0}kb/s  timeleft: {1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D2}", rate, t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds))
}
```

Note that we can write it like this, and avoid the duplication of the method call:

```
String text;
if (t.TotalMinutes < 1) {
   text = string.Format("{0}kb/s  timeleft: {1:D2}", rate, t.Seconds);
} else {
   text = string.Format("{0}kb/s  timeleft: {1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D2}", rate, t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
}
Program.mainForm.AppendLabel(text);
```

Or we could use a ternary (conditional operator):

```
var text = t.TotalMinutes < 1
    ? string.Format("{0}kb/s  timeleft: {1:D2}", rate, t.Seconds)
    : string.Format("{0}kb/s  timeleft: {1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D2}", rate, t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
Program.mainForm.AppendLabel(text);
```

Or we could put it all nicely inside a method:

```
string FormatRemainingText (int rate, TimeSpan t) {
    if (t.TotalMinutes < 1) {
        return string.Format("{0}kb/s  timeleft: {1:D2}", rate, t.Seconds);
    } else {
        return string.Format("{0}kb/s  timeleft: {1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D2}", rate, t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
    }
}
Program.mainForm.AppendLabel(FormatRemainingText(rate, t));
```

Happy coding.

Comment: actually i was looking for the conditional operator ( ? ) but i didnt know how to use it .. thanks alot =)